# /lib/udev/write_net_rules: No such file or directory

Tags: udev

My Linux is suffering from the network configuration, the `70-persistent-rules` file is never generated. I am trying to follow this post: 
https://access.redhat.com/discussions/1240213, but the `udev` program seems to be broken on my machine?

```
$ cd /lib/udev/ && ls 
ata_id                    hpljP1006              pcmcia-check-broken-cis
cdrom_id                  hpljP1007              pcmcia-socket-startup
collect                   hpljP1008              rules.d                        
console-setup-tty         hpljP1505n             scsi_id
hdparm                    hwclock-set            snappy-app-dev
hid2hci                   hwdb.d                 udev-add-printer
hplj1000                  ifupdown-hotplug       udev-configure-printer
hplj1005                  iphone-set-info        usb_modeswitch
hplj1018                  ipod-set-info          v4l_id
hplj1020                  mtd_probe              
hpljP1005                 mtp-probe              
$ /lib/udev/write_net_rule
bash: /lib/udev/write_net_rule: No such file or directory
$ /lib/udev/write_net_rules
bash: /lib/udev/write_net_rules: No such file or directory
```

At this moment I am totally lost. I tried to upgrade udev but doesn't seem to do anything. Any thoughts could be helpful.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Please always add terminal output as text using code block (`{}` button) rather than posting screenshots of it. If you add new information do it by [editing your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/964541/edit) rather than commenting on it.